# Received warning unique key prop while i don't use any list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've received warning like this

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s See
>   fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.%s,
>
> Check the render method of `MainScreen`., , 
>       in MainHeader (at MainScreen.js:164)
>       in MainScreen (created by SceneView)

And it pointed to one of my component called `MainHeader` and when i commented it, the warning is gone. Here's my `MainHeader` looks like

```
const MainHeader = () => {
      return (
        <Header noLeft style={appStyles.headerBackgroundColor}>
            <Body>
              <Title style={appStyles.appTitle}>Whatsapp</Title>
            </Body>
            <Right>
              <Button 
                transparent 
                style={{marginRight:5}}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({searchMode: true})
                }}
              >
                <Icon type= 'Octicons' name= 'search'/>
              </Button>
              <PopupMenu type= 'main'/>
            </Right>
        </Header>
      )
    }
```

As far as i know this warning only appeared in list, can someone explain to me what's going on?

Update: I feel like maybe something is wrong with my way using my component, because i tried to return it to null but the warning still appearing.

This is the line where i called my component

```
showAction ?
              <SelectHeader
                onBack= {resetChatSelected}
                itemCount= {chatSelected.length}
                ComponentRight= {ComponentRight}
              /> :
              <MainHeader/>
```

Comment: It's may occur in one of your child components of your `MainHeader`. So it's better to share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us.

Comment: The error says: `Check the render method of MainScreen.` so maybe check the keys given in that file?

Comment: I'm mainly using `nativebase` component, and i've just tried to return null but the warning still appearing @SMAKSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happened because i have two different component for my statement, so i have to provide key for each of them.

```
showAction ?
              <SelectHeader
                onBack= {resetChatSelected}
                itemCount= {chatSelected.length}
                ComponentRight= {ComponentRight}
                key={0}
              /> :
              <MainHeader key={1}/>
```